# Image from URL doesn't follow the styling rules from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage

So I'm trying to display an Image from URL into a image (connected trough IBOutlet). However, the image does display but does not follow the styling rules set in the storyboard. Such as: Aspect Fill. This results in the image overlapping everything in the simulator.

Code:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.wsvh.nl/wp-content/uploads/bekergoud.jpg")

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.nieuwsFeaturedImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
```

Result: 
[image]

You can see that the image overlaps the title and description.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `[UIImage imageWithData:data scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale]`

Answer (score 2):

If you set aspect fill you'll also need to set `nieuwsFeaturedImage.clipsToBounds = true` or in Interface Builder check the `Clips to Bounds` box.

Without it your image is scaled with respect to ratio and thus it expands beyond the content area you've specified. You will need to truncate all of that extra content - Clips to Bounds is just for that.

[image]

Comment: There are rare cases where this solution will not work. In such cases, you need to use `[UIImage imageWithData:data scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale]` within your code to apply the correct scale to the image.. IE: @2x images do this to me even with ClipToBounds enabled.